# Error while working with sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite

In my Python script, I am seeing the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "F:/python sqllite/test32.py", line 3, 
    in <module> conn.sqlite3.connect('test.db')
  AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'sqlite3'
```

Does anyone have an idea why I might be seeing this?

Comment: You probably want `conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')`

Comment: The message `'sqllite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'sqlite3'` makes me think `conn` is already a connection.  We need to see more of the code.

Comment: I added some context for politeness sake and formatted the error as code to ease readability.  Added tag for SQL Lite.  The OP should really add some more context.

Answer (score 0):

Change: `conn.sqlite3.connect('test.db')`

to    : `conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')`